# Why has the C++ Standard not added "properties" a la C#?

Tags: c++, oop, properties, getter-setter

By properties I mean the C# style properties, with getters and setters.

I am interested to know why they are not a part of the C++ language. I am assuming such a feature must have been discussed while the specification was being written, and so it is a conscientious decision not to include it in the language.

Comment: Because the language is complex as it is, and there must be a really good reason to include something in the core. You can do properties using existing language facilities. Not that you should (see also: quasi-classes).

Comment: You undoubtedly meant "conscious", but yes, "conscientious" is exactly why they weren't included. They're a bad idea, and rejecting them was the right thing to do.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, Yes. I meant conscious. I misspelt it though and it was corrected to conscientious.

Comment: Proposed by Borland, and rejected. See here. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1384.pdf

Comment: The premise of the question is false. You can create data members in C++ classes which evaluate and accept assignment using functions. You can create template classes which let you incorporate such members into a class easily.

Comment: For in `obj.x = 3`, the `x` can actually be of a class type which has an overloaded `=` operator, and that operator knows how to invoke a particular method on `obj` to store a value.   The method can be named in the constructor call to `x` via pointer-to-member syntax. Or, I think, the method can even be a template parameter in the instantiation of the class of `x`.  Of course, `x` can also support being evaluated, which is translated to a different function call.

Comment: @Roddy, I imagined that was the case, do you have any reference for the reply to the proposal? That's the part that I'm interested in.

Comment: I am intrigued as to why this question was closed. Although there is much debate over whether they are a good thing or not, I specifically stayed away from that and asked for the specific reason why the people who write the standard felt they should not be included. Could one of the closers please explain?

Comment: @Mat, No real idea. Just google c++ wg21 N1384 and see what pops up.

Comment: I don't know about a reply to the proposal, but if you search through the archives of comp.std.c++ and comp.lang.c++.moderated, you'll find that yes, it was discussed several times. A number of committee members (Dave Abrahams and Pete Becker, for sure) commented on it -- and none of them particularly favorably that I can recall.

Comment: @Mat I guess it was closed as it's bit of a magnet for uninformed opinions. :(

Comment: From some googling, it seems the closest I can find is the following. Ignoring the code at the end, it does make for a good argument against their inclusion: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1615.pdf

Comment: I think it is also important to note that it is under the list of proposals: "Not ready for C++0x, but open to resubmit in future" according to this page: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2565.html

Answer (score 1):

here is one implementation:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/article.php/c4031/Implementing-a-Property-in-C.htm

```
int i = 5,j;
PropTest test;
test.Count = i;    //-- call the set method --
j= test.Count;     //-- call the get method --
```